# Call PHP Function based on URI

Tags: php

I am looking to create a simple php script that based on the URI, it will call a certain function.

Instead of having a bunch of if statements, I would like to be able to visit:

/dev/view/posts/

and it would call a 'posts' function I have created in the PHP script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func) function documentation.

```
$functions['/dev/view/posts']    = 'function_a';
$functions['/dev/view/comments'] = 'function_b';
$functions['/dev/view/notes']    = 'function_c';

$uri = '/dev/view/comments';

call_user_func($functions[$uri]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a framework? they do this sort of thing for you.

you need to use [mod_rewrite](http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) in apache to do this.

Basically you take /dev/view/posts
and rewrite it to
/dev/view.php?page=posts

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/dev/view/posts/(.*)$ /dev/view?page=$1
```

in view.php

```
switch($_REQUEST['page'])
{
    case 'posts':
        // call posts
        echo posts();
        break;
}
```

**EDIT**  made this call whatever function is called "page"

You probably want to use a framework to do this because there are security implications. but very simply you can do this:

```
if (array_key_exists('page',$_REQUEST))
{
    $f = $_REQUEST['page'];
    if (is_callable($f))
    {
        call_user_func($f);
    }
}
```

Note there are MUCH better ways of doing this! You should be using a framework!!!

Comment: I know about using mod_rewrite, but the problem with that is I need to write code to match each 'posts' with a 'posts' function. Via the framework idea, you can write a function posts() and then just go to /dev/view/posts/ and it will call that function.

Comment: You need whats called a front controller that will map this for you. WHat framework are you using?

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `/` characters.

Comment: sort of relevant, http://twitto.org/ is a great example of taking this to the next level, perhaps a little too far! rather than using a switch statement it checks to see if your controller file has a method  matching the parameter value. not secure, but it makes a point.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a form of URL rewriting on your web server. For instance, if you are using Apache you should lookup mod_rewrite. An example of what your rule might look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dev/view/posts/(.*)$ /posts.php?id=$1
```

But I'm assuming that you are wanting to have a trailing post ID or similar so that you can use this for multiple posts URLs.